# How to execute ansible playbook from crontab?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to execute an ansible playbook from crontab? We have a playbook that needs to run at a certain time ever day, but I know that cron doesn't like ssh.

Tower has a built in scheduling engine, but we are not interested in using Tower. How are other people scheduling ansible playbooks?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use cron jobs to run your playbooks.
Ansible calls ssh with `-tt` switch to force TTY, so it should work nice.
Just check the following:

- job user has access to ssh private keys
- job environment is correct (PYTHONPATH, etc...)
- there is no package mixture on the host (e.g. ansible installed via pip and apt at the same time)

Also check [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/1210#issuecomment-172298551) handy comment about `quiet` option absence in ansible:

> There's a trick for crontab: run ansible-playbook as follows:

```
*/15 * * * *    if ! out=`ansible-playbook yourplaybook.yaml`; then echo $out; fi
```

> This way you get complete output, but only if ansible exited with a non-zero status.

Comment: What about passing `ansible-vault` passwords?

Comment: @AK there's handy `--vault-password-file` [option](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html#running-a-playbook-with-vault) that allows to read password from file or even from other script stdout.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin. I was able to use cron to schedule a different playbook and it worked fine. The playbook I was having problems with contains a python script that seems to be having issues.

Answer (score 2):

It will also work, I am using this to check an agent status and starting it if it is stopped.

```
*/5 * * * * ansible-playbook -i /root/playbooks/agent /root/playbooks/agent.yml
```

Answer (score 2):

We can run as konstantin-suvorov's answer as well as

type

```
# whereis ansible-playbook
  /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
```

and run with the path displayed in the output

**we can run with this in crontab**

```
#crontab -e


*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/ansible-playbook /home/user1/yourplaybook.yml
```

It worked like charm

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same behavior [Konstantin Suvorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2795592/konstantin-suvorov) mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39399538/4173130) by using [croncape](https://github.com/symfonycorp/croncape).

```
*/15 * * * *    croncape ansible-playbook yourplaybook.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

we can create wrapper script in bash like below

```
ANSIBLE_PLAYBOOK=`which ansible_playbook`
cd main_dir_where_playbook_is_located
$ANSIBLE_PLAYBOOK playbook.yaml > log_file
```

save above as run.sh and schedule it like normal cron.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that, but you have to first tell where ansible.cfg is and then start the playbook, and for everything you also have to use full path. Like this:
crontab -e to edit, crontab -l to list

```
# Softwareupgrade
1 5 28 6 * ANSIBLE_CONFIG=/home/xxx/ansible/software-upgrade/ansible.cfg /usr/bin/ansible-playbook -i /home/xxx/ansible/software-upgrade/hosts /home/xxx/ansible/software-upgrade/upgrade.yml
```

If you also would like to view the ansible output, you must also redirect that to a file, like this:

```
# Softwareupgrade
1 5 28 6 * ANSIBLE_CONFIG=/home/xxx/ansible/software-upgrade/ansible.cfg /usr/bin/ansible-playbook -i /home/xxx/ansible/software-upgrade/hosts /home/xxx/ansible/software-upgrade/upgrade.yml >> /home/xxx/ansible/software-upgrade/logfile.log 2>&1
```

That work as long as ansible doesn't return "0"
Unfortunately it becomes very long lines of text in crontab, but it works fine, and you may execute stuff early in the morning or on a regular basis.